# How to merge rows with the same column value on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

One of my daily tasks is to clean up data for my company who deals with multiple clients. The data is purchase data wherein we have the client's name in column A and their monthly purchase in the succeeding columns.

The issue I have is that around the March, a few clients had to be re-registered on our system which caused a double entry of rows under the same client name (1 row for purchases from Jan-March and another row for April-September-but both rows' column A value is the same client name), and now I manually merge all the rows under the same client name.

I've attached an image to illustrate better.

[How the data looks now and desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhNyH.jpg)

Hoping to do this on app scripts since I'll be copy pasting this data on sheets everyday. Would any of you have a workaround / code that can merge row data based on an identical column A value? Greatly appreciate any help as it will save A LOT of time!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: @doubleunary thanks for the tip! here's a copy of the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h8mSlK_jZbegIBM83okdkihUwpEamdPkXadv0X6JaZ4/edit?usp=sharing) I made. The data is exactly as is and I simply changed the name of clients for confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you would want to use a script here, given that a range can be condensed as requested with a plain vanilla spreadsheet `query()` formula that uses `max()`, like this:

```
=query( 
  Sheet1!A2:H10, 
  "select A, max(B), max(C), max(D), max(E), max(F), max(G), max(H) 
   where A is not null 
   group by A", 
  1 
)
```

To replace your original data with the "condensed" data, use <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste values only. On a Mac, use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

The question specifies Apps Script, so here's a custom function to do the same, together with a simple function that uses it to condense a hard-coded range in a spreadsheet.

```
/**
* Merges rows in 'Sheet1!A2:H' by taking the last non-blank value in each
* column, separately for each row group that has the same key in column A2:A.
* The result will include exactly one copy of each key.
*/
function mergeRows() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet1!A2:H');
  const condensed = condenseRows(range.getValues(), 0);
  range
    .clearContent()
    .offset(0, 0, condensed.length, condensed[0].length)
    .setValues(condensed);
}

/**
* Gets exactly one row per each unique key in a key column.
* For each result row, keeps the last non-blank value in each column, separately
* per each row group that has the same key in the key column.
*
* @param {Object[][]} array2D The array to condense.
* @param {Number} columnIndex Optional. The zero-indexed column number where keys appear. Defaults to 0.
* @return {Object[][]} A 2D array where there is just one copy of each key.
* @customfunction
*/
function condenseRows(array2D, columnIndex = 0) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 September 2021
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69205954/13045193
  const hash = {};
  array2D.forEach(row => {
    const key = row[columnIndex];
    if (key === '' || ((key == null))) {
      return;
    }
    if (!hash[key]) {
      hash[key] = [];
    }
    row.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (value !== '' && ((value != null))) {
        hash[key][index] = value;
      }
    });
  });
  const result = [];
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(hash).forEach(key => result.push(hash[key]));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @doubleunary thanks for the response works great although is there anyway to do this on app scripts instead?

Comment: I am assuming that you are asking for a script because you want to keep the data editable. Added a note in the answer that tells how to do that with formula results — "paste values only", together with Apps Script code to do the same.